# How to display manufacturer or seller's information on product page in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have developed a marketplace e-commerce on magento, now I want to display sellers information on product page for ex. name, address, image etc.

1 - How I can achieve this in magento 1.9?

2 - Is it possible to create sub-attribute for manufacturer attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You have the data stored in attributes?

If it is a text attribute use this to echo it:

```
<?php echo $_product->getManufacturer(); ?>
```

where manufacturer is the ID of the attribute.

If it is a dropdown use this to echo it:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("manufacturer"); ?>
```

Make sure the attribute is set to visible on the frontend.

Then you can use Dependent attributes, which work like sub attributes.

Comment: This line of code will print dropdown value not label value.

Comment: @IamManish I assumed it is a text attribute, but yes with dropdowns it is your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');?>
```

This will print selected Dropdown label.